# Override default font style android

Tags: java, android, xamarin

How we can override default font family of entire android device or at least for keyboard programatically.
I have .ttf file,but I am able to find any resource to change the font family of entire device.

Comment: I am not asking for entire android app,I am asking for entire android device(system)

Comment: Are you working in os Level? for changing the font size of device you need to  request  ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>``` but this permission will be granted for app in system/priv-app which are system apps

Comment: and I guess to change the font family of device you need this permission